# find by category in array object returning null in Angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to build a blog application using Angular, node, express in the backend and mongodb as database. Now I'm trying to make a component called blog-categories where there should be a method to iterate the whole database and search by the key **category** and return the values in the component such that all the category values are now shown in the component and when someone will click the values all blogs having such categories will get displayed. In case if you want to have a better look at the project you can check out my git repository https://github.com/tridibc2/blog-admin-mean . But it seems that the route is not able to catch the category. In the header it is going null. When the request is made it is returning localhost:4000/api/v1/blogs/view/by/category/null
The typical database looks somewhat like this:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "All Blogs found Successfully",
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Blog Title 2 Custom edited",
            "description": "Blog description 2 Custom Edited",
            "bodyHtml": "<h3>Heading of the body CUSTOM</h3><p>This is the first blog data getting uploaded n blog project</p>\nedited",
            "views": 9,
            "isPublished": true,
            "category": "Comedy",
            "author": "Decardo",
            "tags": [
                "english movies, action movies, comedy"
            ],
            "blogId": "nbfO8hJp",
            "created": "2020-01-04T23:33:38.000Z",
            "lastModified": "2020-01-04T23:33:38.000Z"
        },
        {
            "title": "Blog Title 2",
            "description": "Blog description 2",
            "bodyHtml": "",
            "views": 1,
            "isPublished": true,
            "category": "tech",
            "author": "Xtremator",
            "tags": [
                "english movies",
                " action movies",
                " comedy"
            ],
            "blogId": "ZW8OR7vc",
            "created": "2020-01-04T23:34:08.000Z",
            "lastModified": "2020-01-04T23:34:08.000Z"
        }
    ] 
}
```

**blog-category.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogpostService } from '../blogpost.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blog-category',
  templateUrl: './blog-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blog-category.component.css']
})
export class BlogCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  public categories;


  constructor(private blogpostService: BlogpostService, private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let myBlogcatrgory = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('category');
    this.blogpostService.viewByCategory(myBlogcatrgory).subscribe(
      data =>{
        console.log(data);
        this.categories = data["category"];
      },
      error =>{
        console.log("some error occured");
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**blog-category.component.html**

```
<h3>Categories</h3>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let category of categories">
            {{category.name}}
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In blog-category.component.ts

ngOnInit() {console.log(data);} what data is printed here in console

Comment: can you please update your latest code in the Github repository?

Comment: The question doesnt seems easy to understand can you please update and only limited code where you are facing issue. Remove unwanted code

Comment: can you put a `console.log(myBlogcatrgory);` after  `let myBlogcatrgory = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('category');` and tell the output?

Comment: @Yogesh.Kathayat it's returning null. Also I updated the github repository

Comment: @mayur console.log(data) is not returning anything

Comment: @surjendu_dey can you try `this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
console.log(params) });` instead of `let myBlogcatrgory = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('category');` and tell the output.

Comment: @Yogesh.Kathayat it is logging the id i.e Object { blogId: "aw-SczEz" }

Comment: ok so do you need this blogId to get your blog by category or the category name??

Comment: the category name listed one after another